# Listbox index display on Label or Textbox

Tags: c#, listview, listbox

Does any one know how to use following commands with  Listbox SelectedIndexChanged event. please let me know. i took this example from the internet and i just want to know how to use it with listbox instead of Listview.

when I don't get the index option after the selected item[0] on listbox  . please help me. 
Thankx guys

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not perfectly accurate but working.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<People> people = new List<People>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        people.Add(new People("Joe Montana"));
        people.Add(new People("Alex Smith"));
        people.Add(new People("Colin Kaepernick"));

        foreach (People p in people)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(p.Name);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = people[listBox1.SelectedIndices[0]].Name;
    }
}

class People
{
    public People(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```